# live encoding/streaming with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to encode large avi (or other) files to mp4, which are then saved to disk, then streamed in the browser using apache mod_h264.

The problem with this is that we have to wait until ffmpeg finishes encoding the mp4, which can take a long time.  Ideally, we would be able to stream the video, while the encoding is being processed.

Is there a way to do this with ffmpeg/mod_h264 or is there a better solution to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With mp4 files, no. You have to wait for it to finish.

Answer (score 0):

It may work. Try adding `-movflags faststart` https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#mov_002c-mp4_002c-ismv to the avi -> mp4 encode

faststart should make the mp4 file streamable/playable before finishing the encode